# Como veo si mi script se ejecuta correctamente

Tags: python

Este es mi script Que se conecta por ssh a un mikrotik y ejecuta un comando 
solo quiero que me vaya diciendo todos los pasos según se vaya cumpliendo.

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('x.x.x.x', username='++', password='+++++++')

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('/ip dhcp-client release [find interface=wlan5]')
```

Comment: `print(stdout)` debería mostrarlo, no?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: la verdad quiero que me devuelva un resultado,si se cumple, o en caso de que el equipo tengo un problema me devuelva otro resultado. En este caso se queda solo pensando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre algo como este.

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('x.x.x.x', username='++', password='+++++++')

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('/ip dhcp-client release [find interface=wlan5]')

while True:
    data = stdout.channel.recv(4096)
    if data:
        text = data.decode()
        print(text)
    else:
        break
```

Con eso podrás mostrar el stdout mientras se ejecuta y cuando ya no haya nada que leer, cierra el ciclo para continuar con lo demás del flujo. No puedo decir que sea una solución perfecta ni siquiera muy buena, pero te puede ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Saelyth, debería bastar con hacer un:

```
print(stdout.read())
```

Sin embargo, esto mostrará el resultado de lo que ejecutaste, de una sola vez, y no en tiempo real, que es lo que entiendo que necesitas cuando dices "según se vaya cumpliendo".